# Labelcontrol In Devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am using DevExpress. How to show html string(especially, bold styled fonts) in xrLabel(devexpress control not .net), like

```
xrLabel1.Text = "My name is <b>Guru</b>. I am in <b>office</b>".
```

If your answer is "use LabelControl and allowHtmlString property", then, share a sample project of using this labelcontrol?

Comment: If you already know the answer then what issues did you have in implementing it?

Comment: Can you implement it and share the .cs file?

Comment: @Sayse This is *Send me teh codez(project)* kinda question :|

Comment: @user1089345 - This is not how stackoverflow works, *you* share *your* code along with issues you are facing when trying to get it to work (if any), along with what you have tried and researched

Comment: I created a DevExprReport. I went to its design-->Scripts part. I written the following code:- LabelControl labelCntrl = new LabelControl();
   labelCntrl.Text = "<size=14>Size = 14<br>" + "<b>Bold</b> <i>Italic</i> <u>Underline</u><br>""; labelCntrl.AllowHtmlString = true; But nothing worked for me. When I run the code, no such label come in the design part.

Comment: I used the following namespaces:- using System.Data;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;

Comment: Did you add the label to the form?

Comment: Dear Sayse, LabelControl is not a drag and drop control. It is a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q288960) topic in DevExpress Support Center:

> It is not possible to render HTML content in the XRLabel control.
>   To accomplish this task, you can use the [XRRichText](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/clsDevExpressXtraReportsUIXRRichTexttopic) control and bind the HTML property of this control to the corresponding property in your DataSource.

Comment: I already contacted DevExprteam, they only asked me to use labelcontrol and not richtext.    https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T181999

Comment: @user1089345 `xrLabel` class is used for `XtraReport` controls. `labelControl` class is used for `Form` controls. According to your question and your comments you are using `XtraReport`. You cannot use `labelControl` class in `XtraReport` controls.

Comment: Ok. Give me a step-by-step procedure of how to use this LabelControl in DevExpress or share me a link if you can find this.

Comment: @user1089345 Here is [`LabelControl`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLabelControltopic) in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it like this:

To load document:

```
richEditControl1.LoadDocument("document.html", DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.DocumentFormat.Html);
```

or for specific control only:

```
string someHtmlText = "<html><body> <p>some test text</p></body></html>";
richEditControl1.HtmlText = someHtmlText;
```

For XtraLabe

```
xrLabel1.Text = "<size=14>Size = 14<br>" +
                     "<b>Bold</b> <i>Italic</i> <u>Underline</u><br>" + 
                     "<size=11>Size = 11<br>" + 
                     "<color=255, 0, 0>Sample Text</color></size>" +
                     "<href=www.devexpress.com>Hyperlink</href>";
xrLabel1.AllowHtmlString = true;
xrLabel1.Appearance.TextOptions.WordWrap = DevExpress.Utils.WordWrap.Wrap;
xrLabel1.Appearance.Options.UseTextOptions = true;
xrLabel1.AutoSizeMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelAutoSizeMode.Vertical;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am working in an XtraReport. There is no drag drop control like Labelcontrol, then how can I use this control. Screenshot attached for reference.

Comment: I have only one control called XRLabel and no LabelControl is given by DevExpress to do the thing.

Comment: @user1089345 It is only variable name. U can replace it what you have in your code. Check my edited answer for more clear view.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! nempoBu4 answer is right only. There is one more control called richText in DevExpress XtraReport. By databinding a html text to this control, it is achievable.(richtext1.Text=some htmlstring property is not working)

Xtra Report has no control called LabelControl.

XrLabel cannot support HTML strings except "\r\n".

Thank you very much every body who has replied to my answer.

I am very sorry if I could not produce the issue upto others' understanding since because of me new to DevExpress.